# Ensure that the controller's request is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controllers

In my app, I have [for example] three controllers: `groups`, `forums`, and `discussions`.

In my `discussions_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
  @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
  @discussions = @forum.discussions
  ...
end
```

So, for example, the URL `/groups/1/forums/1/discussions` renders the same page as `/groups/2/forums/discussions`. Does this mean that in my controllers I'll have to append something like `if @group.forums.to_a.include?(@forum)`? This seems messy and non-rails. I guess I could also create a private method like:

```
def has_forum
  deny_access unless @group.forums.to_a.include?(@forum)
end
```

But this would involve code duplication... so is there something really simple I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant that /groups/1/forums/1/discussions renders the same contents as /groups/2/forums/1/discussions (i.e. specifying the forum_id in both urls) then you could try the following:

```
def index
  @group = Group.find(params[:group_id]
  @forum = @group.forums.find(params[:forum_id])
  @discussions = @forum.discussions
  ...
end
```

That should throw an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if you try and access a forum for the wrong group. You should, however, deny access if the user is not part of the group.

Comment: I knew it must have been something really simple. Thanks!